# Insert statement with where clause doesnt run on nodejs mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, npm

Code:

```
function setvalue(val) {

        idoutput=val;
        base62val=Base.encode(idoutput);
        var baseinsert = {ShortUrlCode:base62val};
        console.log(idoutput);
        console.log(base62val);
        con.query('INSERT INTO URLTABLE set ?  where ID = ?',[baseinsert,idoutput],function(err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        })
        console.log("short inserted");
        con.end();
}
```

Error I am receiving:

```
{ [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where ID = 38' at line 1]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
```

Comment: `... set column_name=?  where...`

Comment: What does this have to do with AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'INSERT INTO URLTABLE set ?  where ID = ?'
```

You forgot to mention column names that you want to "SET".

```
 'INSERT INTO URLTABLE SET column_name = ? (, column_name2 = ?,...) WHERE ID = ?'
```

is the correct syntax

EDIT:

Note that it is always better to "standardize" your SQL queries, in which case you better use the standard SQL syntax below for an INSERT (instead of using your specific MySQL syntax):

`INSERT INTO URLTABLE (a, b, c) VALUES (?,?,?)`

Comment: @RevanthPenugonda Your welcome. Mark the answer as accepted. Everytime you ask a question on SO and that you get the answer you were waiting for don't forget to mark the good answer as accepted