# How to use passed array in nodejs mysql query to compare with specified values?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So i'm trying to figure out how i can insert multiple same rows with same 'ID' but only if 'DATE' value is different than other rows with same 'ID'. I hope that makes sense.

My current query for inserting data is like this.

```
query(`
        INSERT INTO table (id, otherdata, somedata, otherdata, etc, date) 
        VALUES ?
    `, [data])
```

data value looks like this

```
[
    ['id1', 'otherdata1', 'somedata1', 'otherdata1', 'etc1', 'date1'],
    ['id2', 'otherdata2', 'somedata2', 'otherdata2', 'etc2', 'date2'],
    ['id3', 'otherdata3', 'somedata3', 'otherdata3', 'etc3', 'date3'],
    ['id3', 'otherdata3', 'somedata3', 'otherdata3', 'etc3', 'date3'], <- this would be ignored, as id3 and date3 matches with row 3 in this or if such data would exist in database it would do the same.
    ['id3', 'otherdata3', 'somedata3', 'otherdata3', 'etc3', 'someotherDate'], <- this would go through as DATE is different than row3 and only ID matches
    ['id4', 'otherdata4', 'somedata4', 'otherdata4', 'etc4', 'date4'],
]
```

Comment: do you want to access data result or put some condition on where clause?

Comment: i want to put condition on where clause so that the data that's being inserted currently doesn't insert if there's already such item in database with same id and date, does that make sense? Sorry, if not :D

Comment: SELECT ? FROM that **doesn't work** you **can  not** put placeholdeders for colum names

Answer (score 0):

Ah, well. i gave up on doing it in 1 query. I did it into 2. It's quite "ugly" way to do it but will use it while don't know any other work around.

If someone has similar problem, i solved it this way.

id has to be first in array, and date as last. Array format should be like i specified in my post at the top.

```
query(`SELECT id,DATE_FORMAT(date,\'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s\') AS date FROM table WHERE (id) IN(?)`, [data.map(a => a[0])])
    .then(res => {
        data = data.filter(arr => {
            // filter out that already has same id with same date
            if ( !res.some(r => r.id == arr[0] && r.date == arr[arr.length-1]) )
                return arr;
        })

        // if it's empty, return
        if (data.length == 0)
            return console.log("success")

        query("INSERT INTO table (id, ...extra.data.here, date) VALUES ?;", [data])
            .then(() => {
                console.log("success")
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            });
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. So you need pass the array onto the VALUES clause

```
    con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ?";
  var values = [
    ['John', 'Highway 71'],
    ['Peter', 'Lowstreet 4'],
    ['Amy', 'Apple st 652'],
    ['Hannah', 'Mountain 21'],
    ['Michael', 'Valley 345'],
    ['Sandy', 'Ocean blvd 2'],
    ['Betty', 'Green Grass 1'],
    ['Richard', 'Sky st 331'],
    ['Susan', 'One way 98'],
    ['Vicky', 'Yellow Garden 2'],
    ['Ben', 'Park Lane 38'],
    ['William', 'Central st 954'],
    ['Chuck', 'Main Road 989'],
    ['Viola', 'Sideway 1633']
  ];
  con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
  });
});
```

Comment: yes, i know. This would just insert data, even though you'd specify the same data again and it still would insert. What i want to do, if 2 given values match for specified column (in my case id and date) it would ignore inserting that row into database as there already exists with such values.

Comment: it's from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34087982/6357451 where i got the query i used, but i'm not sure how to use it with array, like i passed in query.

Comment: i also updated the topic little bit, with visual explanation, i think it will be easier to understand that way.

Comment: probably when the `id` set as primary key, it wouldn't be inserted as well.

Comment: ah, you're right but i forgot to mention this. I need 'id' to be able to be inserted if the same 'id' is already in database but only if date isn't the same. That's why i want to go this route than using primary key. Only reason for this, is because the data where is coming from, i don't have an access to unique id which can be identified as primary key, i only have access to temporarily id, which is reusable and the created date for that post.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is an upsert. You would need to first define primary/ unique key in your database, such as the `id`

Then run the below query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO books
    (id, otherdata, somedata, otherdata, etc, date)
VALUES
    (data);
```

You can read more about the [IGNORE statement](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/)

Comment: yeah, basically but i want to be able to insert same id's if "date" value is different than for the row that has same "id" value, does that make sense? I'm guessing with UNIQUE keys, that won't be possible?

Comment: You can look up the `Replace` statement. The link in my post has the information. Let me know if it solves the problem

Comment: no i don't think it will work, because like i said. I need for it to be able to insert multiple same IDs if DATE value is different than other IDs have. I don't want to replace existing data with new one.